# onGoing notifications

Tags: android, notifications

Alright, so I know how to create an onGoing notification, but how do I have the notification removed when the application is killed? or if it is killed, when the notification is clicked how to I restart the application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the notification in `onDestroy()` but you cannot guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called at all.
You can, however, put a `PendingIntent` to the notification which will be fired when you click on it, so you will start your app even if it is not running.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "notification Title", "notification Text", pi);
```

Comment: I tried with the pendingIntent, when its destroyed and I click the onGoing notification it throws a null pointer exception

Comment: Try this intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: thanks, the nullPointer was because of an extra it needed, was launching the wrong task! haha